# Unexpected search results on Exchange Online mailboxes by using Search-Mailbox in Power Shell

Tags: powershell, search, exchange-server

From the online documentation I've read the below is a valid query syntax and should return results for emails from the address included in the query only. This is on Exchange Online.

```
Get-Mailbox |Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'From:"invoices@abc.com"' -LogOnly -LogLevel Full -TargetMailbox target@mailbox.com -TargetFolder "Folder"
```

However, it is returning results for invoices@abc.com, invoices@def.com and basically any sender address which includes the word *invoices*. I've tried a few variations with and without the double quotes. Surely this should return results for the full address only or did I miss something in the documentation and examples including on this site?

This variation below does return the correct results but shouldn't be needed.

```
Get-Mailbox |Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'From:invoices AND From:abc.com' -LogOnly -LogLevel Full -TargetMailbox target@mailbox.com -TargetFolder "Folder"
```

Anyone experiencing the same?

Comment: What happens if you omit the inner quotes like `'From:invoices@abc.com'` ?

Comment: I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this successfully. Try using'From:"invoices"@"abc.com"'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).